# Filter for non-NA value based on condition in another column, retaining all other records

Tags: r, dataframe

I am trying to filter out NA values in column SRA when YEAR is 1989. In other words I'd like to retain all values except NA in SRA when YEAR is 1989. This includes retaining the record that has NA values in both the Year and SRA columns

```
SRA <- c(NA, NA, NA, NA, NA, 5, 6, NA, NA, NA, 7, 10, NA, NA, 7, NA)
YEAR <- c(1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1989, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1990, 1991, 1991, NA, NA)
ALLPOP3 <- data.frame(YEAR, SRA)
```

I've tried the following but it filters out the record where YEAR and SRA have an NA value

```
library(dplyr)
ALLPOP4 <- ALLPOP3 %>% 
  filter(YEAR != 1989 | !is.na(SRA))
```

Is there a way I can adjust the code to keep the record where YEAR and SRA have an NA value? Thank you

Desired Output:

```
 YEAR SRA
1  1989   5
2  1989   6
3  1990  NA
4  1990  NA
5  1990  NA
6  1990   7
7  1990  10
8  1991  NA
9  1991  NA
10   NA   7
11   NA  NA
```

Comment: Sorry for the confusion @akrun, but you got what I was looking for below. I'll include the desired output above for clarification. Really appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can use the `&` and negate (`!`)

```
library(dplyr)
ALLPOP3 %>% 
  filter(!(YEAR == 1989 & is.na(SRA))|(is.na(YEAR) & is.na(SRA)))
#   YEAR SRA
#1  1989   5
#2  1989   6
#3  1990  NA
#4  1990  NA
#5  1990  NA
#6  1990   7
#7  1990  10
#8  1991  NA
#9  1991  NA
#10   NA   7
#11   NA  NA
```

---

Or in a more compact way

```
ALLPOP3 %>%
    filter(!(YEAR == 1989 & !is.na(YEAR) & is.na(SRA)))
```

Answer (score 1):

We can do it using `stats::complete.cases`:

```r
ALLPOP3[!complete.cases(ALLPOP3[,c("YEAR","SRA")]), ]

#    YEAR SRA
# 1  1989  NA
# 2  1989  NA
# 3  1989  NA
# 4  1989  NA
# 5  1989  NA
# 8  1990  NA
# 9  1990  NA
# 10 1990  NA
# 13 1991  NA
# 14 1991  NA
# 15   NA   7
# 16   NA  NA
```